# This program takes user input and is supposed to sort it using bubbleSort but its outputting letters and numbers and I'm not sure why

Tags: c++

The output I'm getting when I run this code after inputting any set of integers, and ending the loop with the sentinel number 999, is always 0x7ffd85bc43b0 and I can't figure out why. I think I'm missing some important code somewhere, but I'm not sure where? This program is also eventually supposed to be able to find the mean and median of the inputted numbers as well.

```
// HouseholdSize.cpp - This program uses a bubble sort to arrange up to 300 household sizes in
// descending order and then prints the mean and median household size. 
// Input:  Interactive.
// Output:  Mean and median household size. 

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <any>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
void swapping(int &a, int &b) {      //swap the content of a and b
   int temp;
   temp = a;
   a = b;
   b = temp;
}
void display(int householdSizes, int size) {
   for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){

   }
}
void bubbleSort(int householdSizes[], int size) {
   for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
      int swaps = 0;         //flag to detect any swap is there or not
      for(int j = 0; j<size-i-1; j++) {
         if(householdSizes[j] > householdSizes[j+1]) {       //when the current item is bigger than next
            swapping(householdSizes[j], householdSizes[j+1]);
            swaps = true;    //set swap flag
         }
      }
      if(swaps== false)
         break;       // No swap in this pass, so array is sorted
   }
}
int main() 
{
   // Declare variables.
        
   const int SIZE = 300;    // Number of household sizes
   int householdSizes[SIZE];    // Array used to store 300 household sizes
   int x; 
   int limit = SIZE;
   int householdSize = 0;
   int pairsToCompare;
   bool switchOccurred; 
   int temp;
   double sum = 0;
   double mean = 0;
   double median = 0;

   // Input household size      
   cout << "Enter household size or 999 to quit: ";
   cin >> householdSize;
   
   // This is the work done in the fillArray() function
   x = 0;
   while(x < limit && householdSize != 999)   
   {
      // Place value in array.
      householdSizes[x] = householdSize;
      // Calculate total of household sizes
      
      x++;    // Get ready for next input item.
      cout << "Enter household size or 999 to quit: ";
      cin >> householdSize;
   }  // End of input loop.
        
   
   // Find the mean
   
   // This is the work done in the sortArray() function
   int n = sizeof(householdSizes)/sizeof(householdSizes[0]);
   bubbleSort(householdSizes, n);
   cout <<householdSizes;
   
   // This is the work done in the displayArray() function

   // Print the mean

   // Find the median
   
   // Print the median
            
   return 0;
} // End of main function
```

Comment: I don't understand what is going on. Why is display empty? Where is it displaying an address? I think you are displaying a pointer somewhere.

Comment: `cout <<householdSizes;`  will print the address of that array. Do you want to print the content? `for(int size : householdSizes) cout << size << '\n';`

Comment: You probably only want to bubble sort up to `x`, not `n`.  All values beyond index `x` are uninitialized, and reading them invokes Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Also note that your `n` calculation is entirely unnecessary, because you already know that the array is of size `SIZE`.

Comment: By the way, you may want to look at [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) instead of implementing a swapping function that only works for integers.

Comment: @0x5453, what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

An array can't be printed directly using `cout << householdSizes;` Since an array is convertible to a pointer, that is what is done implicitly behind the scenes. Change `cout << householdSizes;` to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i){
    std::cout << householdSizes[i] << " ";
}
```

P.S. Also do as @0x5453 says. He is right.

Comment: For a task like this use a range-based for loop where possible. Eg `for(int val: householdSizes) cout << val << ' ';`

Comment: @user4581301 he creates an array of size SIZE, but only fills it with x values. I had considered a range-based for loop, but that would obviously not be possible without undefined behavior and an excessive amount of unnecessary looping.

Comment: Good point. Fails the where possible test.